# How can I use javascript/jquery to prevent a decimal point from being typed into an HTML text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field where the user will be entering a number and I want the number to be an integer.  To do this, I want to ignore when a user types a decimal point.

Currently, I have a javascript function that checks the value of the field on keyup, and if the most recent character typed was a decimal point, it is removed.  This creates an effect where the user types a decimal point, it appears, and then disappears.  Is there a way to make the decimal point not show up at all?

Comment: It would be more user-friendly to allow all input but show a message that requests an integer when something invalid is typed.

Comment: i plan to show a message when a user inputs a decimal point as well as removing it

Comment: Don't forget, a user can always paste (ctrl + v) or drag the character in. Instead of preventing a keypress, you should re-check the whole item's value and strip out decimals. Or, do it on the `change` event instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use keypress event:

[http://jsfiddle.net/wAJp7/1](http://jsfiddle.net/wAJp7/1/)

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 46) return false;
}).on('input', function () {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (self.value.indexOf('.') != -1) self.value = parseInt(self.value, 10);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: because otherwise the value of input in the paste handler would be the old value, not the updated one. Try by removing the timeout from the jsfiddle, you will understand what im talking about (pasting value to input using ctrl+v for example)

Comment: Uh, removing everything from the input when pressing a dot is not really desired, is it?

Comment: @Bergi  of course not but as it is not really an OP request i don't take too much of my time on this. Using parseInt() would be more appropriate for sure

Comment: @Bergi looks better now. BTW, not really need of testing for indexOf

Comment: Or just `self.value = self.value.replace(/\./g, "");`…

Comment: @Bergi so in this case: 123.45 becomes 12345, not sure it is better than parsing it to integer

Answer (score 1):

Use a function on `.keydown()` that check wich key is pressed. if it's ".", `preventDefault()`.

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    var kCode = (e.which || e.keyCode)
    if(kCode == 190 || kCode == 110) return false;
    if(e.which === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) return false;
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PsqhJ/1/

Edit: Added preventing user to ctr+v.

Comment: Uh... `190` is `¾`, not `.`.

Comment: if(kCode === 190 || kCode === 110) to fix it for numpad

Comment: Problem here could be as keyup, key code can vary from user culture, that's why for this kind of task, it's better to use keypress event which return the char code not key code

Comment: Yes, you're right @roasted, but with both our answer, we can still add a "." with ctr+v... must fix that! as well!

Comment: You don't need `var kCode = (e.which || e.keyCode)` - jQuery normalizes the keycode into `e.which`, so just test against that

Comment: @roasted, edited my code for the ctr+v, but it doesnt work on keypress. (of course i changed the value for "v"). Any idea why?

Comment: Ctrl+v isn't the only way to paste. You can right click and choose paste, or you could go to the menu bar -> edit -> paste.

Comment: True, missed that, but still doesnt answer my question :)

Comment: i use a workaround with paste event, but well quite weird... There is of course the oninput event too on modern browsers that could be used. To answer your question: no, i don't know why. In fact, keypress is not fired when ctrl is used

Answer (score 1):

```
// don't do anything unless a number key is pressed
$("input").on("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

It's perhaps not the most user friendly solution - it would be more friendly to mark the field as invalid in some way and ask them to correct it - but this will guarantee that you get an integer.

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/unakab/2/edit)

Comment: "the user types a decimal point, it appears, and then disappears" OP doesn't want this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This will stop the user from being able to submit data when it contains a decimal point or any other symbol or letter. There are other ways in which you can stop the user even typing these characters in by checking for key codes but i found it easier by combining the two, as sometimes i want decimal points and sometimes I dont.

Javascript:

```
function NoDecimal(o)
{
    if (o.value.length > 0) 
    {
        var objReg = /^\d{0,10}?$/;
        if (objReg.test(o.value))
        {
            o.style.borderColor='';
            o.style.fontWeight='normal';
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
        }
        else
        {    
            o.style.borderColor='red';
            o.style.fontWeight='bold';
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;
        }    
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
Number: <input type="text" onkeyup="NoDecimal(this);">
```

You can also use onkeyup, onkeydown, onkeypress and oninput but older browsers don't handle oninput as its part of html5. Particularly earlier Internet Explorer Versions